# Must use import to load ES Module after creating vuestorefront project

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-storefront

At first, I created a vuestorefront nuxtjs project using the command

```
npx @vue-storefront/cli generate store
```

with Odoo integration

After that, I created a `.env` file

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8069/
SITE_URL=http://localhost:3000/
# PUBLIC_PATH=https://xyz.cloudfront.cdn.com
# For CI and other deployment scripts

NODE_ENV=dev
NODE_LOCALE=en-EN
PORT=3000
HOST=0.0.0.0

#REDIS_ENABLED=false
#REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
#REDIS_PORT=6379
#REDIS_PASSWORD=pass
# Used for invalidating cache
# INVALIDATION_KEY={get one and add here and inside Odoo}

#NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
#GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID=1
```

After that

```
yarn 
yarn dev
```

It's showing now

> Error
> Must use import to load ES Module: ~/vsfdemo/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.js require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of /home/mohiuddin/vsfdemo/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.js from ~/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename glide.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from ~/vsfdemo/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/package.json

After searching online for many hours I have changed my nuxt.config.js from

```js
transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules'],
```

to

```js
transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules', '@glidejs/glide'],
```

Now it's showing

```
TypeError
Cannot read property '$i18n' of undefined
```

[image: nuxt.js error i18n undefined error photo]

My `nuxt.config.js` file is as follows:

```js
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { getRoutes } from './routes';
import getAppRoutes from './sitemap';
import redirects from './customRoutes/redirects.json';
import theme from './themeConfig';

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export default {
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  },
  components: [
    '~/components/',
    '~/components/Core/Atoms'
  ],
  css: ['@/assets/styles.scss'],
  head: {
    title: 'Vue Storefront',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: '/favicon.ico'
      }
    ]
  },
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes) {
      getRoutes(`${__dirname}`)
        .forEach((route) => routes.unshift(route));
    },
    middleware: ['checkout']
  },
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Roboto: true,
      Montserrat: {
        wght: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
      },
      Lato: {
        wght: [100, 300, 400, 700, 900]
      },
      Raleway: {
        wght: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
      }
    },
    download: false
  },
  pwa: {
    meta: {
      name: 'VSF Odoo',
      theme_color: '#fff',
      lang: 'en',
      description: 'VSF Odoo',
      twitterCard: 'summary_large_image'
    },
    manifest: {
      name: 'VSF Odoo',
      description: 'VSF Odoo',
      short_name: 'VSFOdoo',
      lang: 'en'
    },
    icon: {
      purpose: 'maskable'
    },
    workbox: {
      cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
      preCaching: [
        '/error/error.svg',
        '/icons/*',
        '/favicon.ico'
      ]
    }
  },
  device: {
    refreshOnResize: true
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/getImage.ts',
    '~/plugins/vee-validate.ts'
  ],
  buildModules: [
    // to core
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxt/image',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
    '@nuxtjs/web-vitals',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',

    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',
    [
      '@vue-storefront/nuxt',
      {
        performance: {
          httpPush: true
        },
        // @core-development-only-start
        // @core-development-only-end
        useRawSource: {
          dev: ['@vue-storefront/odoo', '@vue-storefront/core'],
          prod: ['@vue-storefront/odoo', '@vue-storefront/core']
        }
      }
    ],
    // @core-development-only-start
    [
      '@vue-storefront/nuxt-theme',
      {
        routes: false
      }
    ],
    // @core-development-only-end
    /* project-only-start
    ['@vue-storefront/nuxt-theme'],
    project-only-end */
    ['@vue-storefront/odoo/nuxt', {}]
  ],
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    theme,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    siteURL: process.env.SITE_URL
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    'nuxt-precompress',
    '@nuxt/image',
    '@vue-storefront/middleware/nuxt',
    'nuxt-i18n',
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
    ['@vue-storefront/cache/nuxt', {
      enabled: (process.env.REDIS_ENABLED === 'true') || false,
      invalidation: {
        endpoint: '/cache-invalidate',
        key: '0ead60c3-d118-40be-9519-d531462ddc60',
        handlers: [
          '@vue-storefront/cache/defaultHandler'
        ]
      },
      driver: [
        '@vue-storefront/redis-cache',
        {
          defaultTimeout: 86400,
          redis: {
            host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
            port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
            password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD || ''
          }
        }
      ]
    }],
    // google tag manager
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
    // sitemap generator
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    // redirect
    '@nuxtjs/redirect-module'
  ],

  // google tag manager
  gtm: {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID,
    enabled: !isDev,
    pageTracking: true,
    pageViewEventName: 'PageView',
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  },

  // redirect
  redirect: {
    statusCode: 301,
    rules: redirects
  },

  nuxtPrecompress: {
    enabled: !isDev,
    report: false,
    test: /\.(js|css|html|txt|xml|svg)$/,
    // Serving options
    middleware: {
      // You can disable middleware if you serve static files using nginx...
      enabled: true,
      // Enable if you have .gz or .br files in /static/ folder
      enabledStatic: true,
      // Priority of content-encodings, first matched with request Accept-Encoding will me served
      encodingsPriority: ['br', 'gzip']
    },

    // build time compression settings
    gzip: {
      enabled: !isDev,
      // compression config
      // https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin
      filename: '[path].gz[query]',
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      compressionOptions: { level: 9 }
    },
    brotli: {
      enabled: !isDev,
      // compression config
      // https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin
      filename: '[path].br[query]',
      compressionOptions: { level: 11 },
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    }
  },
  i18n: {
    baseUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,
    strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
    currency: 'USD',
    country: 'US',
    countries: [
      { name: 'US', label: 'United States' },
      { name: 'DE', label: 'Germany' },
      { name: 'RU', label: 'Russian' }
    ],
    currencies: [
      { name: 'EUR', label: 'Euro' },
      { name: 'USD', label: 'Dollar' },
      { name: 'RUB', label: 'Rubble' }
    ],
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        label: 'English',
        file: 'en.json',
        iso: 'en'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        label: 'German',
        file: 'de.json',
        iso: 'de'
      },
      {
        code: 'ru',
        label: 'Russian',
        file: 'ru.json',
        iso: 'ru'
      }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    lazy: true,
    seo: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      numberFormats: {
        en: {
          currency: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
          }
        },
        de: {
          currency: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'EUR',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
          }
        },
        ru: {
          currency: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'RUB',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      cookieKey: 'vsf-locale'
    }
  },

  // sitemap options
  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.SITE_URL,
    exclude: ['/checkout/**', '/checkout', '/cart', '/my-account', '/order-history'],
    i18n: false,
    cacheTime: 6000,
    gzip: true,
    defaults: {
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: new Date()
    },
    routes: getAppRoutes,
    filter: ({ routes }) => {
      return routes.filter(route => {
        return route.path?.toLowerCase() === route.path;
      });
    }
  },

  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      require.resolve('@storefront-ui/shared/styles/_helpers.scss', {
        paths: [process.cwd()]
      })
    ]
  },
  build: {
    //standalone: true,
    babel: {
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }]
      ]
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false
      }
    },
    transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules', '@glidejs/glide'],
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map';
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.VERSION': JSON.stringify({
          // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
          version: require('./package.json').version,
          lastCommit: process.env.LAST_COMMIT || ''
        })
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

the `package.json` file is as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "@vue-storefront/odoo-theme",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-var nuxt build -m --dotenv $VSF_RC",
    "build:local": "nuxt build -m --dotenv .env",
    "test:e2e": "cypress open --config-file tests/e2e/cypress.json",
    "test:e2e:hl": "cypress run --headless --config-file tests/e2e/cypress.json",
    "build:analyze": "nuxt build -a -m",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "update:check": "ncu",
    "update:update": "ncu -u",
    "update:routes": "node hooks/execute.js routes",
    "update:redirects": "node hooks/execute redirects",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adyen/adyen-web": "^5.23.1",
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.6.1",
    "@nuxt/types": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/amp": "^0.5.4",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/redirect-module": "^0.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "1.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/web-vitals": "^0.1.8",
    "@storefront-ui/vue": "0.13.3",
    "@vue-storefront/cache": "^2.6.0",
    "@vue-storefront/middleware": "2.5.4",
    "@vue-storefront/nuxt": "2.5.4",
    "@vue-storefront/nuxt-theme": "2.5.4",
    "@vue-storefront/odoo": "1.4.0",
    "@vue-storefront/redis-cache": "^1.0.1",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.5.0",
    "nuxt-precompress": "^0.5.9",
    "redis-tag-cache": "^1.2.1",
    "vee-validate": "^3.2.3",
    "vue-i18n": "8",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.17.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "latest",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "cypress": "7.5.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "nuxt-vite": "^0.3.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~2.0.6",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

Sorry if the way of questioning is wrong. I am completely stuck with this problem. I am completely new to NuxtJS and VueJS

```
node version: v14.20.1
npm version:  6.14.17
Nuxt version: v2.15.8 
yarn:         v1.22.19
```

Here is the given Vue file

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <SfButton
      class="container__lang container__lang--selected"
      @click="isLangModalOpen = !isLangModalOpen"
    >
      <SfImage
        :height="20"
        :width="20"
        :src="addBasePath(`/icons/langs/${locale}.webp`)"
        alt="Flag"
        class="language__flag"
      />
    </SfButton>
    <SfBottomModal
      :is-open="isLangModalOpen"
      title="Choose language"
      @click:close="isLangModalOpen = !isLangModalOpen"
    >
      <SfList>
        <SfListItem v-for="lang in availableLocales" :key="lang.code">
          <a :href="switchLocalePath(lang.code)" @click="$i18n.setLocale(lang.code)">
            <SfCharacteristic class="language">
              <template #title>
                <span>{{ lang.label }}</span>
              </template>
              <template #icon>
                <SfImage
                  :src="addBasePath(`/icons/langs/${lang.code}.webp`)"
                  :width="20"
                  :height="20"
                  alt="Flag"
                  class="language__flag"
                />
              </template>
            </SfCharacteristic>
          </a>
        </SfListItem>
      </SfList>
    </SfBottomModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  SfImage,
  SfSelect,
  SfButton,
  SfList,
  SfBottomModal,
  SfCharacteristic
} from '@storefront-ui/vue';
import { ref, computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import { addBasePath } from '@vue-storefront/core';
export default {
  components: {
    SfImage,
    SfSelect,
    SfButton,
    SfList,
    SfBottomModal,
    SfCharacteristic
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    const { locales, locale } = context.root.$i18n;
    const isLangModalOpen = ref(false);
    const availableLocales = computed(() =>
      locales.filter((i) => i.code !== locale)
    );
    return {
      availableLocales,
      locale,
      isLangModalOpen,
      addBasePath
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, mind sharing the given `.vue` file where you do have this error? Because the rest seams fine.

Comment: Here is the file. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YVfpFGHQPk/  located at /components/LocaleSelector.vue

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for the module error in your question!

Answer (score 0):

In your `nuxt.config.js` file, you made a typo in the `modules` section.
Here is the correct name of the module

```js
'@nuxtjs/i18n' // rather than 'nuxt-i18n'
```

Here is the link in the doc: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/setup

---

The rest works fine on my side, I didn't face any other issues by replicating your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After building and deploying VSF, i got the Server Error

```
ERROR  require() of ES Module /workspace/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.js from /workspace/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js not supported.
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45] glide.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45] Instead rename glide.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /workspace/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45] 
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45] 
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   glide.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   Instead rename glide.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /workspace/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at /workspace/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:76653
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:/external "@glidejs/glide":1:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at Module.433 (15.js:844:14)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async server.js:15008:21
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async Promise.all (index 0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async getRouteData (.nuxt/utils.js:180:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async Promise.all (index 0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async setContext (.nuxt/utils.js:266:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async createApp (.nuxt/index.js:136:0)
[vsf-shop] [2023-04-19 11:51:45]   at async module.exports.__webpack_exports__.default (.nuxt/server.js:84:0)
```

What solved my issue was setting the version to `3.5.2` in the `package.json` as resolution `"resolutions": { "@glidejs/glide": "3.5.2" }`

as mentioned here https://github.com/vuestorefront/storefront-ui/issues/2494

Another way is to set

```
"@vue-storefront/middleware": "~2.5.4",
"@vue-storefront/nuxt": "~2.5.4",
"@vue-storefront/nuxt-theme": "~2.5.4",
```

to `2.7.5` that also solves the problem